# Connecting HTML/DOM with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to find a way to write to a text file using node.js but I was trying to get the input from the HTML DOM. How do you write the output from the DOM to a text file using fs.writeFile?

Here's some code that doesn't work but thought it might be relevant. Thanks

```
<h3>A demonstration of how to access a Text Field</h3>

<input id="myText">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

const fs = require('fs')

function myFunction() {
  var content = document.getElementById("myText").value;
}

fs.writeFile('./test.txt', content, err => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return
    }
})

</script>
```

Comment: Where do you want to write the file to?

Comment: I think, you are confused between frontend and backend. Instead create a normal HTML, when clicked collect the data and send it to nodejs backend using Ajax on your html file. and then in backend nodejs write the data to the file.

Comment: Okay great thanks. I'll try looking into Ajax

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write file directly from a browser to local computers.
That would be a massive security concern.
*You also cannot use `fs` on client-side browser

Instead you get inputs from a browser, and send it to your server (NodeJs), and use `fs.writeFile()` on server-side, which is allowed.

What you could do is:

1. Create a link and prompt to download.
2. Send to server and response with a download.
3. Use native environment like `Electron` to able NodeJs locally to write into local computer.

What I assume you want to do is `1`
Is that case you could simply do:

```
function writeAndDownload(str, filename){
    let yourContent = str
    //Convert your string into ObjectURL
    let bom = new Uint8Array([0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf]); 
    let blob = new Blob([bom, yourContent], { type: "text/plain" });
    let url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
    //Create a link and assign the ObjectURL
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    link.style.display = "none";
    link.setAttribute("href", url);
    link.setAttribute("download", filename);
    //Automatically prompt to download
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}

writeAndDownload("Text you want to save", "savedData")
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I’ll try looking into Electron. I know you can use different databases etc but I’m trying to do it without using any frameworks. 

So when you say you can send it from the browser to the server, I’m not entirely sure what that would involve? Someone earlier suggested I could use Ajax to send the file. I’ll try looking into that. Thanks for the help though.